# Fourier Series Representation of Discontinuous Function

Tags: fourier-series

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 1& \text{ if } -1\leq x < 0 \\ 
 1/2 & \text{ if } x = 0 \\ 
 x& \text{ if } 0 < x \leq 1 
\end{cases} \text{for the interval} [-1,1]$

So I understand that you suppose to calculate the integral for every region but here at x = 0 function is 1/2. So should I add the f(0) value? For example for calculating $a_0$

$a_0 =\int_{-1}^{0}1dx +\int_{0}^{1}xdx$

or should i add f(0) value

$a_0 =\int_{-1}^{0}1dx +\int_{0}^{1}xdx + f(0)$

Comment: Please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: At points of discontinuity, the Fourier series will converge to the mean of the left and right limits, so in this case, the series will converge to $1/2$ at $x=0.$

Comment: The integral doesn't depend on the value of the integrand at one specific point.

Comment: So am I suppose to ignore x= 0 point? Then how come series will converge to 1/2 at x = 0. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Think about integral as area under graph of the function. In such setting "area" of the rectangle which has as a base "single" point and finite height is zero.